# find by email and return last record sent mongoose - express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am working on a microservice that takes care of sending random OTP (one time passcode) passcodes by email.

Here is my model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


let otpCodeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
      type: String,
      default: 'email'
    },
    otpCode: {
        type: String,
        default: '0'
    },
    OTPTimeStamp:{
        type: Date,
        default: new Date()
    }
}, {timeStamps: true});


let otpCodeModel = mongoose.model('OTP', otpCodeSchema);

module.exports = otpCodeModel;
```

I create otp-codes using this function:

```
router.post('/generate-passcode/:email', (request, response) =>{

let randomCounter;
randomCounter = uuid.v4();
if(randomCounter === 0){
    randomCounter;
}

//saving passcode to database as a {key:value} pair = {email:passcode}
let emailParameter = request.params.email;
let myOTPCodeModel = new otpCodeModel({email: emailParameter, otpCode: randomCounter});

let savedOTPCode = myOTPCodeModel.save();

//send code to user's email

});
```

Here is my method:

```
    router.get('/findbyemail/:email', async (request, response) =>{
    try {
        let requestEmail = request.params.email;
        let myOTPCode = await otpCodeModel.findById({email: requestEmail});
        let code = otpCodeModel.otpCode;
        response.status(202).json(code);
    }catch(error){
        response.status(400).json({ErrorMessage: `Error: ${error}`});
    }
});
```

My Question:

In the above method/endpoint **'/findbyemail/:email'**,  when I feed it an email (request.params.email), it gives me the following error:
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ email: 'myemail@gmail.com' }" (type Object) at path "_id" for model "OTP""

What I want to achieve:
I want to feed it an email, it returns the last otp-code that was sent ?

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose's **findById** method casts the id parameter to the type of the model's _id field That is why it gives you CastError
Use fineOne for finding any user by Email or by Other Object

```
let myOTPCode = await otpCodeModel.findOne({email: requestEmail});
```